# I'm writing to declare a function that accept a dictionary as argument. The function should return a new_dict with swap keys and values

Tags: python-3.x

While running the function, I got TypeError, Please where do I go wrong

```
channel = {
   2: "CBS",
   4: "NBC",
   5: "FOX",
   7: "ABC"
 }
def stations_to_numbers(channels):
    my_dict={val:key for key,val in channels.items()}
    return my_dict

print(stations_to_numbers(**channel))
```

TypeError: stations_to_numbers() keywords must be string

Answer (score 1):

The print statement

```
print(stations_to_numbers(**channel))
```

tries to call

```
stations_to_numbers( **{2:"CBS", 4:"NBC", 5:"FOX", 7:"ABC"})
```

The syntax you are using (wrongly) is for providing a dictionary of `paramnames:values` to a function:

```
def f(a,b,c):
    print(a,b,c)

f( **{"a":42, "b":52, "c":62}) # prints '42 52 62'
```

whereas the *paramnames* have to be strings (as the error tells you).

You want to do

```
print(stations_to_numbers(channel))  # no **
```